# apache 2.4 + how to rewrite /index

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm working with apache 2.4 and using mod rewrite, all good with

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1

it will map /blog to index.php?q=blog as expected but never for /index to index.php?q=index

why's that, is "index" a keyword in apache?  Didn't see any useful from searching google and apache doc. BTW I'm on ubuntu 14.04.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's related to the default vhost setting:

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

remove last "MultiViews" and it worked.